# Validating contents on Next button click in jWizard Framework

Tags: swing, jwizard

Here is my problem. I wanted to implement an "installation wizard" in Swing. I stumbled upon [jWizard](http://code.google.com/p/jwizard-framework/) framework and I liked the look-and-feel of the wizard. Unfortunately, I have not been able to come up with a solution for validating the contents of the wizardPane when the Next Button is clicked. What ever I seem to do, it continues to the next screen.

I understand that I have to put the validation logic in the function below:

```
public void applyState() throws InvalidStateException {}
```

Can anyone show me an example on how to stop the wizard pane from showing the second screen in case of an invalid input?

Comment: I got the solution to this problem. I took the original code, tweaked the NextAction code so that it moves to the next screen only if the complete boolean flag is true. I can manipulate the complete boolean flag from my wizard by setting the setComplete() function.

Answer (score 1):

can you use cout and print some of the properties?

cout << wizardpane.getName() << endl;